# Dynamic Progress Bar

Tags: python, progress-bar, mathematical-optimization, percentage

I have a dynamic progress bar function I made to use in a debugging application. Everything works as intended but I need help condensing the code to be more efficient.

```
def progress_bar(current_value, **kwargs):
    top_left_border = u'\u2554'.encode('utf-8')
    top_right_border = u'\u2557'.encode('utf-8')
    bottom_left_border = u'\u255A'.encode('utf-8')
    bottom_right_border = u'\u255D'.encode('utf-8')
    horizontal_border = u'\u2550'.encode('utf-8')
    vertical_border = u'\u2551'.encode('utf-8')
    color_border = '\33[38;5;3m'
    color_fg = '\33[38;5;4m'
    color_bg = '\33[48;5;4m'
    color_inverted_fg = '\33[38;5;0m'
    color_end = '\33[0m'

    b_val = int(current_value)
    b_width = 50
    b_max = 100
    b_min = 0
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if k.lower() == 'width': b_width = v
        elif k.lower() == 'max': b_max = v
        elif k.lower() == 'min': b_min = v
        elif k.lower() == 'fg':
            if 0 <= v <= 255:
                color_fg = '\33[38;5;{}m'.format(v)
        elif k.lower() == 'bg':
            if 0 <= v <= 255:
                color_bg = '\33[48;5;{}m'.format(v)
        elif k.lower() == 'reverse':
            if 0 <= v <= 255:
                color_inverted_fg = '\33[38;5;{}m'.format(v)
        elif k.lower() == 'border':
            if 0 <= v <= 255:
                color_border = '\33[38;5;{}m'.format(v)

    if b_min >= b_max:
        print color('Minimum value cannot be greater than or equal to maximum value.', 'red')
        return
    if b_val < b_min: b_val = b_min
    if b_val > b_max: b_val = b_max
    if b_width < 10: b_width = 10

    # top border
    print color_border + top_left_border + horizontal_border * (b_width - 2) + top_right_border + color_end

    # progress bar fill count, percentage string and starting position of string
    fill_cnt = int(round(float(b_val - b_min) / (b_max - b_min) * (b_width - 2)))     # filled spaces
    fill_pct = str(int(round((float(b_val - b_min) / (b_max - b_min)) * 100))) + '%'  # % string
    pct_pos = int(round((b_width - 2) / 2) - round((len(fill_pct) / 2) - 1))          # start position of %

    # build the percentage bar string & percentage text
    b_bar = color_border + vertical_border + color_end

    if fill_cnt >= pct_pos:
        # if filled bar position ends after start of text
        num_dig = pct_pos - 1  # number of spaces before text
        b_bar += color_bg + ' ' * num_dig + color_end
        if fill_cnt < pct_pos + len(fill_pct):
            # if filled bar ends within text block
            num_dig = fill_cnt - pct_pos + 1  # how many digits of text are filled
            b_bar += color_bg + color_inverted_fg + fill_pct[:num_dig] + color_end
            b_bar += color_fg + fill_pct[num_dig:] + color_end  # unfilled text digits after
            num_dig = (b_width - 2) - (pct_pos + len(fill_pct) - 1)  # blank spaces after text
            b_bar += color_fg + ' ' * num_dig + color_border + vertical_border + color_end
        else:
            # if the filled bar position ends after the end of text
            b_bar += color_bg + color_inverted_fg + fill_pct + color_end  # percentage text
            num_dig = fill_cnt - (pct_pos + len(fill_pct) - 1)  # filled bar positions after end of text
            b_bar += color_bg + ' ' * num_dig + color_end
            num_dig = (b_width - 2) - fill_cnt  # number of blanks after filled bar
            b_bar += color_fg + ' ' * num_dig + color_border + vertical_border + color_end
    else:
        # if the filled bar position end before start of text
        b_bar += color_bg + ' ' * fill_cnt + color_end  # filled bar spaces
        num_dig = pct_pos - fill_cnt - 1  # blanks after fill & before start of text
        b_bar += color_fg + ' ' * num_dig + fill_pct + color_end
        num_dig = (b_width - 2) - (pct_pos + len(fill_pct) - 1)  # blanks after end of text
        b_bar += color_fg + ' ' * num_dig + color_border + vertical_border + color_end
    print b_bar

    # bottom border
    print color_border + bottom_left_border + horizontal_border * (b_width - 2) + bottom_right_border + color_end
```

Usage: progress_bar(value, **kwargs)
kwargs: width=50, max=100, min=0, fg=foreground color index, bg=background color index, reverse=foreground color index of inverted text, border=color index of border

kwargs are optional.

I was unable to streamline the code and had to make 3 separate cases to handle different lengths of the filled progress bar.

Side note: this is on a work computer so I only have access to the standard library and cannot use some modules such as tkinter. I am also limited to Python 2.7.15

Comment: This fits to [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not SO.

Comment: I don't come here often I was unaware code review was even a thing. Thank you.

Comment: You must update Python3.12